# includeContext on <s:a> Struts 2 tag not work

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, struts-tags

According to the documentation I can use the `includeContext = "false"` to avoid that actual context should be included in the URL.

When I using this line:

```
<s:a action="persist" namespace="books" includeParams="get" includeContext="false" cssClass="btn btn-xs btn-success">
   <s:text name="actions.books.edit" />
   <s:param name="idBook"><s:property value="id" /></s:param>
</s:a>
```

The generated URL is this:

```
http://localhost:8080/ejercicio4-web/books/books/persist.action?idBook=6
```

But the current URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/ejercicio4-web/books/all.action
```

If I use the `<s:url>` component if it works correctly:

```
http://localhost:8080/ejercicio4-web/books/persist.action?idBook=6
```

The `struts.xml` complete config:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <!-- Use Guice as the ObjectFactory for this application -->
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="guice" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    <constant name="struts.url.includeParams" value="get" />
    <!-- Default App Package -->
    <package name="app-default" abstract="true" extends="struts-default, tiles-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="saveParamsOnSession" class="interceptors.SaveParamsOnSession"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="secure">
                <interceptor-ref name="roles">
                    <param name="allowedRoles">ADMIN</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
            <interceptor-stack name="storeFlashDataStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
            <interceptor-stack name="storeParamsPrepareParamsStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
                <interceptor-ref name="saveParamsOnSession" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <global-results>
            <result name="ejbexception" type="tiles">app.error.ejbexception</result>
        </global-results>
        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="javax.ejb.EJBException" result="ejbexception" />
        </global-exception-mappings>
    </package>
    <!-- Books package -->
    <package name="books" namespace="/books" extends="app-default">
        <!--<default-interceptor-ref name="secure"/>-->
        <default-action-ref name="home" />
        <action name="home" class="actions.BaseAction">
            <result type="tiles">app.books.home</result>
        </action>
        <!-- persist book -->
        <action name="persist" class="actions.books.PersistBookAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <result type="tiles">app.books.persist</result>
        </action>
        <action name="proccess" class="actions.books.PersistBookAction" method="proccess">
            <interceptor-ref name="storeParamsPrepareParamsStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.io.IOException" result="input" />
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">persist.action?idBook=${book.id}</result>
            <result type="redirectAction">persist.action?idBook=${book.id}</result>
        </action>
        <!-- Show Book -->
        <action name="show" class="actions.books.BookAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
            <result type="tiles">app.books.show</result>
        </action>
        <action name="pdf" class="actions.books.ShowPDFAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="test.pdf"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
        </action>
        <!-- Remove book -->
        <action name="remove" class="actions.books.RemoveBookAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">all</result>
            <result type="redirectAction">all</result>
        </action>
        <!-- Books list -->
        <action name="all" class="actions.books.BooksAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="storeParamsPrepareParamsStack" />
            <result type="tiles">app.books.all</result>
        </action>
    </package>
     <!-- Authors package -->
    <package name="authors" namespace="/authors" extends="app-default">
        <action name="create" class="actions.authors.CreateAuthorAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="storeFlashDataStack" />
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">books/persist</result>
            <result type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">persist</param>
                <param name="namespace">/books</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
    <!-- Accounts package -->
    <package name="accounts" namespace="/accounts" extends="app-default">
        <action name="login" class="actions.accounts.SigninAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result>/WEB-INF/views/accounts/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="check" class="actions.accounts.SigninAction" method="check">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">login</result>
            <result type="redirectAction">login</result>
        </action>
        <action name="signup" class="actions.accounts.PreCreateUserAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result type="tiles">app.accounts.signup</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">app.accounts.signup</result>
        </action>
        <action name="create" class="actions.accounts.PostCreateUserAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store">
                <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">signup</result>
            <result type="redirectAction">signup</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: You have used a `namespace` attribute in `<s:a>` tag.

Comment: I need to use the namespace attribute. In <s: url> I also use it and there is no problem

Comment: Which S2 version? What is your package namespace? Try `<s:a action="persist" namespace="/books">`.

Comment: I am using struts 2.5.2. If using namespace = "/ books" the resulting URL is this: http://localhost:8080/books/persist.action?idBook=6. Should be http://localhost:8080/ejercicio4-web/books/persist.action?idBook=6.

Comment: Look at my snippet there is no `includeContext` attribute.

Comment: yes, I have removed includeContext as your snippet. And the result is localhost:8080/books/persist.action?idBook=6.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe you have changed something that interfere with url construction.

Comment: thanks, I think there is nothing strange. The project is here https://github.com/sergio11/struts2-hibernate, in case you want to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `includeContext` attribute? You should remove it

```
<s:a action="persist" namespace="books" cssClass="btn btn-xs btn-success">
   <s:text name="actions.books.edit" />
   <s:param name="idBook"><s:property value="id" /></s:param>
</s:a>
```

The framework is using `UrlHelper` to generate urls for all tags, so they can't predict how do you use a generated code. `includeContext` is a `Boolean` property that means

> "Whether actual context should be included in URL"

---

> [**Description**](http://struts.apache.org/docs/a.html)
>
> A tag that creates a HTML .This tag supports the same attributes
>   as the "url" tag, including nested parameters using the "param" tag.

Also why did you use `includeParams="get"`? Only one parameter in the url.

Comment: Use includeContext to avoid concatenating the url of the action with the current one as I explained above.  If I use <s: url> with includeContext = 'false' if it works correctly, it does not concatenate the current url with that of the action.

Comment: includeParams="get" Is to prevent for example if the current URL is http:// localhost: 8080/exercise4-web/books/all.action?query=styles do not generate http: //localhost: 8080/exercise4-web/books /persist.action?query =styles&idBook = 6.  Because default is includeParams = "all". 
But it is not working either

Comment: Besides, as you well said : <s:a> supports the same attributes as the "url" tag. But the results obtained are not the same.